# Table and subtable numbering at use of the *\ContinuedFloat* and *talltblr*

Tags: tables, floats, tabularray, subtables

**Edit:**
improved is (I hope so) the problem description.

In cases, when tables had to be encapsulated into `subtables` environments (defined in `caption` package), which are in two successive `table`'s floats which should have the same caption label, the macro `\ContinuedFloat` take a care for `table` float as well for `subtable`s if tables are use `tabular`, `tabularx`, ... tables as well when is used `tblr` table defined in the `tabularray` package.

However, when you for some reason need `talltblr` (that you can write notes and remarks below table body), situations is dramatically changes:

- macro `\ContinuedFloat` doesn't influence on captions in `talltblr`
- `subtable` doesn't influence on caption in `talltblr`

This I have try to solve by removing caption in `talltblr` with `\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}`. It remove caption, but not also incrementing (interestingly) of `table`  counter, so before `\end{table}` should be add `\addtocounter{table}{-1}`.

Further problem is that caption in `subtable` doesn't increment as it do at `tblr`. This also can be cure by adding `\addtocounter{subtable}{1}` before caption in the second `subtable`. Both manually changed counters works in document text but completely fail in `\listoftables`. Consequently, this way to solve problems of tables numbering, when is used `talltblr`, is not useful.

I wonder, if anyone know for better way how to solve this problem or this should be feature request to the package author?

Not so short MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, counter}


\begin{document}
\listoftables

%%%%%%%% tblr
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}
\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty  =,
    input-close-uncertainty =,
    table-format={(}1.3{$^{***}$}, % reserve space for text before/after numbers
         }

    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
\caption{Caption Text, \texttt{tblr}}
\label{tab:1}
%
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
    \centering
\caption{first sub table}
\label{tab:1-1}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={ l *{5}{S} },
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries, guard},
                     }
    \toprule
A    &  B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F                   \\
    \midrule
1   & 1.234
            & 1.234 & 1.234
                            & 1.234 & 1.234                 \\
    &(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)                \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{subtable}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[!ht]\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\caption[]{Caption Text, \texttt{tblr} -- \textit{Continued}}
%
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
    \centering
\caption{second sub table}
\label{tab:1-2}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={ l *{5}{S} },
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries, guard},
                     }
    \toprule
A    &  B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F                   \\
    \midrule
2   & 5.678 
            & 5.678 & 5.678 
                            & 5.678 & 5.678                 \\
    &(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)                \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{subtable}
    \end{table}
\endgroup    

%%%%%%%% talltblr
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}

\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty  =,
    input-close-uncertainty =,
    table-format={(}1.3{$^{***}$}, % reserve space for text before/after numbers
         }
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
\caption{Caption Text, \texttt{talltblr}}
\label{tab:1}
%
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
    \centering
\caption{first sub table}
\label{tab:1-1}
    \begin{talltblr}[
note{}  = {SE in parentheses: 
          *:    $p<0.10$,\quad
          **:   $p<0.05$,\quad
          ***:  $p<0.01$.
          },
                    ]{colspec={ l *{5}{S} },
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries, guard},
                     }
    \toprule
A    &  B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F                   \\
    \midrule
1   & 1.234\TblrNote{*}
            & 1.234 & 1.234\TblrNote{**}
                            & 1.234 & 1.234\TblrNote{***}   \\
    &(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)                \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{subtable}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[!ht]\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\caption[]{Caption Text, \texttt{talltblr} -- \textit{Continued}}
%
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
    \addtocounter{subtable}{1}
    \centering
\caption{second sub table}
\label{tab:1-2}
    \begin{talltblr}[
note{}  = {SE in parentheses:
          *:    $p<0.10$,\quad
          **:   $p<0.05$,\quad
          ***:  $p<0.01$.}
                    ]{colspec={ l *{5}{S} },
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries, guard},
                     }
    \toprule
A    &  B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F                   \\
    \midrule
2   & 5.678\TblrNote{*}
            & 5.678 & 5.678\TblrNote{**}
                            & 5.678 & 5.678\TblrNote{***}   \\
    &(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)                \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{subtable}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
    \end{table}
\endgroup

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
    any table body
  \caption{Test of table numbering}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To downvoter: what is wrong with my question that you downvote it?

Comment: +1 :) I think the question is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add `label=none,entry=none,` to the `talltblr`. The first one make sure the counter isn't incremented, the second one suppresses an entry in the list of tables. You need this because both aspects are covered by the `subtable`.

You then don't have to manipulate the `table` counter.

By the way, what is the purpose of the `\begingroup ... \endgroup`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, counter}


\begin{document}
\listoftables

%%%%%%%% tblr
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}
\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty  =,
    input-close-uncertainty =,
    table-format={(}1.3{$^{***}$}, % reserve space for text before/after numbers
         }

    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
\caption{Caption Text, \texttt{tblr}}
\label{tab:1}
%
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
    \centering
\caption{first sub table}
\label{tab:1-1}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={ l *{5}{S} },
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries, guard},
                     }
    \toprule
A    &  B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F                   \\
    \midrule
1   & 1.234
            & 1.234 & 1.234
                            & 1.234 & 1.234                 \\
    &(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)                \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{subtable}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[!ht]\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\caption[]{Caption Text, \texttt{tblr} -- \textit{Continued}}
%
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
    \centering
\caption{second sub table}
\label{tab:1-2}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={ l *{5}{S} },
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries, guard},
                     }
    \toprule
A    &  B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F                   \\
    \midrule
2   & 5.678 
            & 5.678 & 5.678 
                            & 5.678 & 5.678                 \\
    &(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)                \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{subtable}
    \end{table}
\endgroup    

%%%%%%%% talltblr
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}

\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty  =,
    input-close-uncertainty =,
    table-format={(}1.3{$^{***}$}, % reserve space for text before/after numbers
         }
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
\caption{Caption Text, \texttt{talltblr}}
\label{tab:2}
%
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
    \centering
\caption{first sub table}
\label{tab:2-1}
    \begin{talltblr}[label=none,entry=none,
note{}  = {SE in parentheses: 
          *:    $p<0.10$,\quad
          **:   $p<0.05$,\quad
          ***:  $p<0.01$.
          },
                    ]{colspec={ l *{5}{S} },
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries, guard},
                     }
    \toprule
A    &  B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F                   \\
    \midrule
1   & 1.234\TblrNote{*}
            & 1.234 & 1.234\TblrNote{**}
                            & 1.234 & 1.234\TblrNote{***}   \\
    &(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)                \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{subtable}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[!ht]\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\caption[]{Caption Text, \texttt{talltblr} -- \textit{Continued}}
%
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
    \centering
\caption{second sub table}
\label{tab:2-2}
    \begin{talltblr}[label=none,entry=none,
note{}  = {SE in parentheses:
          *:    $p<0.10$,\quad
          **:   $p<0.05$,\quad
          ***:  $p<0.01$.}
                    ]{colspec={ l *{5}{S} },
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries, guard},
                     }
    \toprule
A    &  B   &   C   &   D   &   E   &   F                   \\
    \midrule
2   & 5.678\TblrNote{*}
            & 5.678 & 5.678\TblrNote{**}
                            & 5.678 & 5.678\TblrNote{***}   \\
    &(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)&(0.123)                \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{subtable}
    \end{table}
\endgroup

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
    any table body
  \caption{Test of table numbering}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! So simple! Is this documented somewhere in package documentation? If yes, so far I didn't find it :-).   Group is left from some real document, that  `sisetup` and `\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}` is limited to enclosed tables. In this particular case `sisetup` can be moved to preamble, ``\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}`  (since doesn9t work as I expected) deleted together with `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup`.

Comment: This is documented in the `tabularray` documentation, just above section 4.2.

Comment: Indeed. I should read documentation more carefully... Thank you very much for info.